# Error interpretando jpeg imagen al descargar

Tags: php, ftp

El error es el siguiente:

```
"(Error interpreting JPEG image file (Not a JPEG file: starts with 0x3c 0x70)"
```

Y este es mi script para descargar archivos:

```
//Extensión del archivo para elegir el mime type
switch ($ext) {
case 'pdf':
  $headerType = 'application/pdf';
  break;
case 'png':
  $headerType = 'image/png';
  break;
case 'jpg':
  $headerType = 'image/jpg';
  break;
case 'jpeg':
  $headerType = 'image/jpeg';
  break;
case 'gif':
  $headerType = 'image/gif';
  break;
case 'xls':
  $headerType = 'application/excel';
  break;
case 'doc':
  $headerType = 'application/msword';
  break;
default:
  $headerType = 'application/octet-stream';
  break;
}

header('Content-type: '.$headerType.'');

$fp = fopen("php://output", "w");
ftp_fget($conn_id,$fp,$value,FTP_BINARY, 0);
```

En mi servidor si lo puedo abrir bien, pero al momento de descargarlo por medio del sistema me ocurre ese error, es algún error con el mimeType o es otra cosa?

Comment: 0x3c 0x70 es "<p".  Está seguro que está descargando un jpeg y no una pagina HTML?  Que pasa si usa $headerType = 'application/text' ?

Comment: Efectivamente, estaba revisando linea por linea el código del script y tenia unos echos de más ahí, eso estaba haciendo que saliera dañada la imagen. problema resuelto gracias.